# Cómo ajustar ventana a la rotación de pantalla en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Queria saber cómo ajusto los container y contenidos que tengo en una ventana a la rotación de pantalla ya que cuando se rota no se ven unas cosas... O simplemente bloquear la rotación, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `MediaQuery` para obtener el tamaño de la pantalla.

Ejemplo:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    final screenHeight = screenSize.height;

    return Container(width: screenWidth);
  }
```

Para prevenir la orientación puedes ver la respuesta aceptada aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418332/flutter-how-to-prevent-device-orientation-changes-and-force-portrait?rq=1